# why is the value of state evaluated only once in asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Why is the value of count evaluated only once if called like `setCount(count + 1)` if the code is asyonchronous?
When you press the button `Increment Count Twice Async Naive` it triggers two `timeOut()`, one with 500ms delay and other with 1000ms delay. So, I thought that since the first `timeOut` triggers a re-render through `setCount(count + 1)`, the value of count should be updated in the second `timeOut`? Since 500ms is plenty of time to execute the operation and a re-render should cause `count` to be updated at the time the function of the second `timeOut` is invoked.

The second button `Increment Count Twice Async Robust` works correctly if you pass a function to `setCount`. So if count is one, it becomes 3. Why is the state evaluated at time of invocation unlike the previous button?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [triggerAsyncIndex]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [triggerAsyncIndex]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerRobustAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          setCount(prev => {
            return prev + 1;
          }),
        500
      );
    }
  }, [triggerRobustAsyncIndex]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerRobustAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          setCount(prev => {
            return prev + 1;
          }),
        1000
      );
    }
  }, [triggerRobustAsyncIndex]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment Count</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setTriggerAsyncIndex(triggerAsyncIndex + 1)}>
        Increment Count Twice Async Naive
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => setTriggerRobustAsyncIndex(triggerRobustAsyncIndex + 1)}
      >
        Increment Count Twice Async Robust
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State updates in functional components are not just async but also bound by closure and it doesn't matter if you use a setTimeout, they will still refer to the value in which the function was defined

Since the below useEffect functions are only re-triggered on `triggerAsyncIndex` change, a count state update will not lead to the updated value being reflected in the second useEffect since it has already been created before the count has updated

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [triggerAsyncIndex]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerAsyncIndex > 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [triggerAsyncIndex]);
```

It required a new re-render for the count value to be refreshed in the function closures. The old function invocations will still continue to hold the previous closure values.

The ideas in such cases is to use function state updates like `setCount(prev => prev + 1)`

Comment: I see. So because [triggerAsyncIndex] has not changed, the environment (including value of count) in which the second setTimeout triggers is still the same. So why does passing (prev => prev + 1) update it, since it does not trigger a re-render because [triggerAsyncIndex] did not change?

Comment: That is because react makes sure that it internally passes the updated value to the setState call also this isn't affected by closure as the values is received from the function callback argument and not from the enclosed scope

Comment: So, you can see react as another internal closure, which does hold the updated state and calling it like (prev => prev + 1) gives React a chance to pass the updated value. So like every closure is it's own chamber locked in time. The only way to change that chamber is to either re-create(re-run) it or acces an updated chamber containing the current chamber, correct?

Comment: There is another way apart from the two that you suggest. You can copy the state to ref inside a useEffect and since refs works on mutation, the updated value will be seen within the function